# Understanding results of the cloud based load test in VSTS

Tags: load-testing, c#, test-report

As part of load testing I ran the set of same API's for several iterations with different user loads. My concern is with the total requests made against the user load. All tests were ran for 10 minutes duration.

In the first iteration I got a report of 1388 total requests for 100 users. 
[image]

For the second iteration, I got a report of 1393 total requests for 500 users.
[image]

My concern is if there are 1388 requests for 100 users, I was expecting 1388*5 (ie.6940 requests) for 500 users, but I am getting only 1393 requets. Can someone help me understand how this logic works for getting the total number of requests made against an API in load testing.

Comment: I'd start with those "Learn more" links - it looks to me like to increase the number of requests hitting the server you would need to increase the number of virtual origin points. What you're seeing is more or less equivalent to a single thread - 2.3 requests/sec * 60s * 10 = 1380 total requests. You're not going to get more total requests in 10 minutes without increasing the number of requests/second.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you either have a load balancer enforcing a limit or your testing software is fixed at 2.3 rps.